# How does Obi-Wan Kenobi analyze Anakin's blood?

Tags: star-wars

When everyone is stuck on Tatooine, Qui-Gon has Obi-Wan analyze Anakin's blood, by Qui-Gon placing it inside his communicator. What actually happened?

Comment: I don't remember Alec Guinness ever doing anything like that, are you sure you're thinking about Star Wars and not some other happy-fluffy-bunny kids movie?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He didn't just put the blood into any old communicator - [his com has a special attachment that is designed to analyze blood for a midichlorian count](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian#Study_and_analysis).  It does the reading locally, and transmits the results over the data line to the other end.  This could be used by, for example, a Jedi in a hospital nursery to take samples from a large number of newborns as part of a standard screen, reporting the results to a central server for processing.

Essentially, it seems that most Jedi (or perhaps only those of Master rank) have coms that allow them to do on-the-spot blood analysis.  It's perfect for when you are dispatched to remote worlds to search for new Jedi potentials.  If it's cheap enough, there's really no reason NOT to give all your Jedi the ability to check people for potential - the Force works in mysterious ways, and you might just end up on a rink-a-dink backwater and stumble across a strong power in a young child.

Comment: I get the impression that this test isn't limited to just the Jedi, but seems to be a standard test that would be run by all hospitals or doctors in the Republic.  Either that, or blood samples or scans from all newborns, were submitted to the Jedi temple.  Quigon makes the comment that if Anakin had been born in the Republic, he would have been spotted and raised as a Jedi.  There can't possibly be enough Jedi about to spend their time going from hospital to hospital testing children throughout the Republic.

Comment: @BBlake: Of course not, but someone has to train the nurse staff in the use of the specialty equipment.  As the linked article says, the test IS standard in all the Republic's hospitals.

Comment: Well cheap in the movie too. Didn't they use a womans razor?

Comment: I was able to buy one of these in 1999. It didn’t analyze blood samples for Midichlorian levels, but it did allow Qui-Gon to say “Obi-Wan, he will bring balance.  Train him” and Mace Windu to say “Party’s over, m——-f——-!”

Answer (score 5):

When I visited [Star-Wars Identities : The Exhibition](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/08/star-wars-identities-the-exhibition/) I took this ominous photo :

[image: Meson taloscope]

And here is the legend :

[image: Legend]

So, according to this, it's this *machine* that did the test.

How?

(...)

*This space has been left intentionally blank.*

It just did, OK.

Comment: this device looks like it came from the Dr Who universe.

Answer (score 1):

The most specific description I've found of this process comes from *The Phantom Menace: The Expanded Visual Dictionary* (2012). The book pictures a prop of a blood swab test kit with a data port, and explains:

> Qui-Gon takes a blood sample from Anakin and transmits the profile to Obi-Wan, who tests the sample's levels of midi-chlorians: symbiotic microbes that allow beings to feel and use the Force.
>
> [...]
>
> Jedi test kits employ swabs treated with a chemical that reacts to midi-chlorians.

This seems to confirm that he's just sending locally-collected data about the blood to the Royal Starship, not somehow teleporting the blood for analysis. It's less clear why the field test kit relies upon external analysis if all of the relevant data can be found onsite, but, speculatively, reasons could include:

- Obi-Wan is interactively controlling the reader remotely via the "meson taloscope", which has to be done manually
- The field kit wasn't designed with a readout display for cost/size/power reasons
- Measuring midi-chlorian levels requires complicated statistical analysis that requires advanced computing hardware

Comment: The republic doesn't have the money for midichlorian kit displays, one off slave purchases, and shooting down empty life pods.